# VB.NET 2K8: How to make all imports visible within a class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, import, reference

Generally speaking, a common VB.NET class should look like the following:

```
Public Class MyClassName

End Class
```

Besides, I have already seen, if I remember correctly, all of the import statements visible just like in C#:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq

Public Class MyClassName

End Class
```

How to make these default imports visible by default in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008?

Is there some setting or the like in the options I shall set?

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.  The VB.NET Language spec only mentions "implicit imports" without giving an authoritative list.  I can reverse-engineer it from the command line as shown in the output window, VS2008 and VS2010 uses this /Imports command line option:

- Microsoft.VisualBasic,
- System,
- System.Collections,
- System.Collections.Generic,
- System.Data,
- System.Diagnostics,
- System.Linq,
- System.Xml.Linq

MSBuild sets these in Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets from the Import variable.   Which is set in the .vbproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Import Include="System" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Import Include="System.Linq" />
    <Import Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Altering the Project + Reference setting *does* alter this list but there's no obvious one-to-one correspondence since this screen changes *assembly* references, the `<Import>` build variable lists name spaces.  I'll have to punt, this ultimately is determined by the project template.

Comment: Thanks for this list. Is that for .Net 4 projects?

Comment: As documented, both for VS2008 and VS2010.

Comment: But IDE != .NET target, and Linq doesn't exist in .NET 2.0, regardless of the IDE version.

Comment: Removing assembly references culls the implicit imports list as well.  I documented this as well.

Comment: +1 Besides, does this mean that I have to reverse-engineer to make them appear in my classes? There's something I'm missing in your answer, sorry.

Comment: You can't make them appear.  If you want to make this squeaky clean then delete the list in the .vbproj file and type the Imports directives by hand in every source code file.  This is how C# works.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the project in Visual Studio then go to Properties. On the "References" tab there is a list of imported namespaces at the bottom. Anything added there doesn't need to be imported for any file in the project.

So to see the ones that are defaulting, you can just look there. :)

Comment: +1 You're right about mentioning where I may see them in the references tab from within the project properties. Aside, I wonder how to make them explicitly visible from within the class code. Thanks for your time! =)

Comment: I found this interesting: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/imports.htm

Comment: These are *assembly references*, the Imports directive applies to namespaces.

Comment: @HansPassant Note that this tab also allows you to check and uncheck namespaces you want to import, so you can use this tab to control which namespaces your program is using (in addition to `Imports` in the source code). If you uncheck everything in this tab, your namespace setup will become like C# where you need to put `using` for each namespace. The references tab might be a little easier than editing the vbproj file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're thinking 'Imports xxlibnamexx'

And as far as I am aware, if they are not in the text source file, they may just be System related ones that are intrinsically imported.

Comment: +1 For pointing my mistake - yes, that is `Imports System`, etc. I corrected it. I know they are intrinsically imported, and I wonder how to make those imports expressly visible in the code of the class. Do you have any idea? Thanks for your time reading my question, and for your answer too. =)