# How To Use VB.NET IList(Of T).Max

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, ilist

How do I use the [IList(Of T).Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) function in my example below?

```
Dim myList as IList(Of Integer)

For x = 1 to 10
    myList.add(x)
Next

'Error: 'Max' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of Integer)'
MsgBox(myList.Max())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code throws a System.NullReferenceException when calling myList.add because it has not been initialized. If you use List instead of IList as shown below it works.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)

        For x = 1 To 10
            myList.Add(x)
        Next

        MsgBox(myList.Max())

    End Sub
End Module
```

It works fine even if only System is imported in the project.

Comment: I don't see how that code works without importing `System.Linq` since `List` does not define a Max method.

Comment: Maybe that is implicitly imported. For instance the vbc compiler does it for you with both System.dll and System.Core.dll and maybe more but I didn't try to explicitly reference them using the command line.

Comment: Just for reference, I found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094365/vb-net-2k8-how-to-make-all-imports-visible-within-a-class) which describes which namespaces are implicitly imported in VB 2008/2010. It includes the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Excellent, that explains everything. Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 5):

You have to make sure you `import System.Linq`, and add the `System.Core.dll` as a reference to your project.

This is because `Max` is an extension method defined in `System.Linq.Enumerable` class. It is *not* defined in `System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of T)` interface.