# there is a List.Max() in vb.net but i got Public member 'Max' on type 'List(Of Integer)' not found

Tags: vb.net

basically, what i'm trying to do is to get the maximum number from a `List(Of Integer)` in VB.Net. And there is this `Max` method in the List class. Based on the method name, this could solve my simple problem, but instead i got an error.

what i have done is like this:

```
Dim l as New List(Of Integer)
l.Add(3)
l.Add(8)
l.Add(7)

Dim mx as Integer = l.Max()
```

but i got `Public member 'Max' on type 'List(Of Integer)' not found.` error on `l.Max()`

what did i do wrong? and what is the proper way to use it?

**edit:**

based on the example in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298374(v=vs.110).aspx it should be okay

Comment: `Imports System.Linq`, make sure you have that declared in your class at the top. It's a needed namespace and your target framework must be >= 3.5...

Comment: @Zaggler no luck, after adding the import, still got the same error

Comment: What framework you targeting?

Comment: @Zaggler i'm targeting framework 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have manage to make it work, pheww, thank for the help

what i do to make it work is change the code as follows:

```
Dim l as New List(Of Integer)
l.Add(3)
l.Add(8)
l.Add(7)

Dim mx as Integer = Enumerable.Max(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add:

```
Imports System.Linq
```

(As @Zaggler suggested.)

And add a reference for `System.Core.dll`

Original post with this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630756/7538975).

Comment: `System.Core` is automatically added when a project is created in frameworks >= 3.5. I asked him what framework he was targeting because of the possibility he may be coming from a 2.0 or other older framework. If that is the case then most definitely he would need the core namespace, but if project gets upgraded to a newer framework, it should add required library automatically.

Comment: @Zaggler Indeed. I suggested the adding of the reference because I'd assume after that the adding of the reference would be the next step. (If they didn't just want to upgrade the Framework)

Comment: @SirKamui the problem in the post you linked is not the same, it was because it did not get initialized with `New`

Comment: @Zaggler Be that as it may, they were attempting to use the same Function "Max", and the answer addressed that. Which is what i was referring to.