# Import namespaces C# vs. VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, namespaces

In C# you need a lot of namespaces and in VB not for the same classes from the same namespaces.

C# example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

VB example:

```
Import System.Collections.Generic
Import System.Drawing
Import System.Drawing.Printing
Import System.Linq
Import System.Text
```

Why you need less imports in VB then in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET 2K8: How to make all imports visible within a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094365/vb-net-2k8-how-to-make-all-imports-visible-within-a-class)

Comment: VB automatically adds references for more things I think.  System and Forms for isntance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB projects have `Imported Namespaces` (Project properties -> References tab) which indicates the default namespaces to Import for each file inside the project. `System` and a few other namespaces are added to this list by default.